# How to create NuGet package that add only JavaScript/CSS to web-based project?

Tags: nuget

I have some NuGet package that contains both DLL file and web related files like JavaScript, Stylesheet and image files. I want to create package that only install web related file to web project only (including ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC project). What is the easiest way to do that?

**Thanks,**

PS. I think it should be possible via Powershell script. But I think, it is quite complex for me.

Comment: Why don't you want to include the dll into the web project? What are you packaing? Does it make sense to have 2 packages?

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I need to install only DLL to other like class library. In the other hand, I need to install both DLL and web related file (including JS and CSS) to web project like ASP.NET website or ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: You're probably going to need to learn a bit of PowerShell.

Comment: Currently, I decide to move dll into main package and use another package for web-related files only. However, this way doesn't solve problem for long term development.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76538608/6259522

Answer (score 12):

You probably want to use the [Nuget Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer).  It allows you to create a package without the command line and add only the required files to your package (plus some easy config).

If I understand you correctly, you sometimes want to install just the DLL, and sometimes the DLL plus the web stuff.  In this case it's best to create a separate package for the DLL, then another package with the web stuff which specifies the DLL package as a dependency of the Web package.  This way it will automatically add the DLL when you add the Web content.

[Here's a tutorial on Nuget Package Explorer](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/781/package-javascript-library-nuget) that will probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which I am using in several projects which works pretty nicely.

Create a second .Assets project, which contains the Assets, and reference all the files as links in your project, and mark them as embedded resources.

YourProject.Assets - contains the css/html/js/cshtml files
YourProject - files included as links, marked as Embedded Resource

Then include my [EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider](https://nuget.org/packages/EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider/) Nuget package, and it will serve you assets from the Embedded Resources in YourProject.dll.

If someones wants to override the resources, they can install the .Assets nuget package and they will be included in their project and served.

Comment: It isn't normal way to deploy JavaScript or image file in NuGet package because web server cannot optimize for this kind of resource. But this solution might works for some package that doesn't want to add any other file to deployed project rather than their dll.