# Create Nuget package for dot net core project from static files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have created npm package which has js and css files just similar to bootstrap as folder structure. I want to ship same package for .Net mvc web applications so I created `.nuspec` file specifying `files`  from build output and created Nuget package. Both the Nuget and NPM package working great.

Now I want to publish same package for dot net core project. When I install same Nuget package in dot net core web application it installed successfully but does not copied static files to project folders.

How to create/fix nugget package of static files for dot net core application. I don't want to create .net core project to ship static files. It would be great if I could add some configuration file like `.nuspec` for dot net core application as well.

I have searched but not able to get any help in regards, So any suggestion or reference would be appriciated.

`myproject.nuspec`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <title>MyProject</title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <projectUrl>some url...</projectUrl>   
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>This is similar to bootstrap</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="jQuery" version="[3.0.0, 4.0.0)" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="dist\css\**\*.*" target="content\Content\css" />
    <file src="dist\fonts\**\*.*" target="content\Content\fonts" />
    <file src="dist\js\mypackage.js" target="content\Scripts" />
    <file src="dist\images\**\*.*" target="content\Content\Images" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Update : I tried solution given below by @thatguy it does copied the files in appropriate folders. I can see those in Visual Studio. But that newly created files and folder has arrow symbol on it while other files does not. I tried including css in page code but it does not found the newly created files.

What this arrow means and why its not finding the files ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it seems that `contentFiles` in .NET Core does not support this scenario the way that `content` did before, see these related posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994668/nuget-package-contentfiles-artifacts-installed-as-links-in-asp-net-core-mvc-proj), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55287761/net-core-nuget-package-copy-files-to-package-consumer-wwwroot?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Also, you should keep the name of  `<package_id>.props` the same as the `package_id`.

Comment: Hi Dipak, any update about this issue? Could you please tell us any progress about this issue? And we could give you any support if you want.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT It worked as expected. Just a issue is it create files in .NET MVC project as well in .Net Core. Is there any way to condition it to only .NET core project ?

Comment: If you want copy these files only in `net core` project, you should abandon using `content` node in `nupkg`.It will automatically copy files into the NET Framework main project when you install the package

Comment: I have updated my answer. See `update 1`.

Comment: @DipakTelangre  If my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to mark it.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Create Nuget package for dot net core project from static files

You should use [<package_id>.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) file.

**1)** create a folder in your **MyPackage** called `build` and then add a file called `MyPackage.props` file in it.

[image]

**2)** Then add these in it:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="CopyFilesToProject" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Copy css files to project" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <SourceScripts Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\content\**\*.* "/> //file from the nuget package
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy
       SourceFiles="@(SourceScripts)"
       DestinationFiles="@(SourceScripts -> '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"   
         />
  </Target>
  
</Project>
```

**3)** change to use this **nusepc** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <title>MyProject</title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <projectUrl>some url...</projectUrl>   
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>This is similar to bootstrap</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="jQuery" version="[3.0.0, 4.0.0)" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="dist\css\**\*.*" target="content\Content\css" />
    <file src="dist\fonts\**\*.*" target="content\Content\fonts" />
    <file src="dist\js\mypackage.js" target="content\Scripts" />
    <file src="dist\images\**\*.*" target="content\Content\Images" />
    <file src="build\MyPackage.props" target="build" />
  </files>
</package>
```

**4)** repack your project **MyPackage** and then first uninstall the old nuget package **MyPackage** first in your main project.

**Then**, [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all caches under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

**After that**, install the new version **MyPackage** and then **build** your project first and you can see the files be copied under the main project.

**In addition**, there is [a similar issue about your request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348993/include-only-xml-file-of-specific-nuget-package-in-a-different-folder) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63489674/how-to-include-resx-file-in-a-nuget-package/63499163#63499163).

==================================

**Update 1**

If you want these files only be copied on **Net Core** projects, you should abandon using **content** node in `nupkg`. It will automatically copy files into the NET Framework main project when you install the package.

Instead, you could put these files under a different folder called **resource** of the **nupkg**.

You could follow my steps:

**1)** change `MyPackage.props` file to:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="CopyFilesToProject" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Copy css files to project" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <SourceScripts Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\resource\**\*.* "/> //file from the nuget package
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy
       SourceFiles="@(SourceScripts)"
       DestinationFiles="@(SourceScripts -> '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"   
         />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

**2)** change `xxx.nuspec` file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <title>MyProject</title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <projectUrl>some url...</projectUrl>   
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>This is similar to bootstrap</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="jQuery" version="[3.0.0, 4.0.0)" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="dist\css\**\*.*" target="resource\Content\css" />
    <file src="dist\fonts\**\*.*" target="resource\Content\fonts" />
    <file src="dist\js\mypackage.js" target="resource\Scripts" />
    <file src="dist\images\**\*.*" target="resource\Content\Images" />
    <file src="build\MyPackage.props" target="build" />
  </files>
</package>
```

**3)** then repack your project and install the new one, before it, you should clean nuget caches first.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer ! It 's working as expected.

Comment: This worked after changing the path in the .prop file from

`<SourceScripts Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\content\**\*.* "/>`

To

`<SourceScripts Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\content\**\*.* "/>`

Answer (score 0):

In our organization, we wanted to share static files across different dotnet projects (css files, icons, fonts, js files). We created a NuGet package inspired by Mr Qian's answer.

#### Step 1: Nuspec file

First, create a file named `ProjectName.nuspec` with the following content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ProjectName</id>
    <description>A NuGet package containing static files</description>
    <authors>AuthorName</authors>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="dist\css\**" target="content\css" />
    <file src="dist\assets\**" target="content\assets" />
    <file src="build\ProjectName.props" target="build" />
    <file src="build\template.gitignore" target="content\.gitignore" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Here, the files we want to distribute are the css files in `dist\css\` and some other files in `dist\assets\`.

#### Step 2: Props file

Then, create a file called `ProjectName.props` and place it in a folder called `build`. It should contain:

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="CopyFilesToProject" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Copy files to project" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <SourceScripts Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\content\**\*.* "/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceScripts)" DestinationFiles="@(SourceScripts -> '$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\wwwroot\ProjectName\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This script will copy over all the files to the folder `ProjectName` which is placed in `wwwroot`.

#### Step 3: .gitignore file

We want to also copy over a .gitignore file such that the files being copied over to the projects that use this NuGet package are not checked into git. The files will always be copied over to the project when building the project, so we want these files to be ignored by git.

Create a file called `template.gitignore` and place it in the `build` folder with the following content:

```
# This file is included in the NuGet package with the name .gitignore such that none of these files will
# be checked into projects that uses this package. The files are copied into the repository when building
# the project with the NuGet package.

# Ignore all files in the folder
*
```

#### Step 4: Pack NuGet package

You will need the NuGet client tool (nuget.exe): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools

Run `nuget pack ProjectName.nuspec` and you have your NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the files to my project and added couple of lines in the .csproj file

Here `Config_files` is the place I added the static files and `C2` is the path I declared to store in the folder, It can be of your choice

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Config_Files\C2\**">
        <PackagePath>content\Config_Files\Get2</PackagePath>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Ref image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKWmp.png)